# Tab jQuery doble menu control

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have the following tab, but I can not put the active menus for both work simultaneously when you click on one menu or another.

Any way to make the tabs are already controlled manner vertically or horizontally and active in both menu is maintained?

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/9mqf8ar0/1/

```
$(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lean on the same href value, and identify the elements based on that, something like

```
$('.tabs-menu a[href="' + href + '"]').parent().addClass("current");
$('.tabs-menu a').not('a[href="' + href + '"]').parent().removeClass("current");
```

here is a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9mqf8ar0/2/